# In Next.js, how to create a bg image that covers the entire browser window

Tags: html, css, reactjs, next.js

In the following picture, we have to apply height 100% to both html and body tags. But how to do that in a `next.js` component??

Refer [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/K1r9l.png

[2] https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_full_page.asp

"mainImage.jsx"

```
import React from 'react';
import './mainImage.css'

export default ()=>(
    <div>
        <div className="bg"></div>
    </div>
)
```

"mainImage.css"

```
.bg {
    /* The image used */
    background-image: url("/public/jeep3.jpg");

    /* Full height */
    height: 100vh;

    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

after applying height:100vh; i just show the empty div with length not the image.

Comment: Hi, Can you add you basic code please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change height value to :

```
.bg {

height:100vh;

}
```